# How to get every value of a key of a JSON file with multiple dicts?

Tags: python, json

How to get every value of a key of a  JSON file with multiple dicts? I want to extract every value of `"username"` key.

`data.json`

```
{
    "1476439722046238725": {
        "tweet_id": "1476439722046238725",
        "username": "elonmusk",

    },
    "1476437555717541893": {
        "tweet_id": "1476437555717541893",
        "username": "billgate",
    },
    "1476437555717541893": {
        "tweet_id": "1476437555717541893",
        "username": "jeffbezos",
```

This is what my code so far but it gave me this error `KeyError: 'username'`.

`main.py`

```
import json
with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data["username"])
```

Comment: You get a `KeyError` because `data` is the _entire dictionary_ given by that json. It has no key `"username"`. The _values_ in `data` are also dicts and these _do_ contain a key `"username"`, so you want to ask the question "how do I iterate over the items in a dictionary", which is a question that's been asked and answered many times before, both on Stack Overflow and in other tutorials on dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enumerate through the outer dictionary.

```
import json
with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for val in data.values():
    print( val['username'] )
```